# form content goes into tab section issue Magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminform

I am creating a form for admin but my form content display on tab section instead of content area, I have  tried several possibility but never succeed, so someone can guide me at some point to resolve this issue ?

Here is my `layout` file

`NAME_MODULENAME_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="NAME\MODULENAME\Block\Adminhtml\OrderField\Edit" name="modulename_edit"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <block class="NAME\MODULENAME\Block\Adminhtml\OrderField\Edit\Tabs" name="modulename_edit_tabs">
                <block class="NAME\MODULENAME\Block\Adminhtml\OrderField\Edit\Tab\Main" name="modulename_edit_tab_main" />
                <action method="addTab">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">main_section</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">modulename_edit_tab_main</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

My block edit file

```
<?php

namespace NAME\MODULENAME\Block\Adminhtml\OrderField;

class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container {

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize blog post edit block
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct() {
        #$this->_objectId = 'field_id';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_orderField';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'NAME_OrderField';

        #$this->_mode = 'edit';

        parent::_construct();

        $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save Field'));
        $this->buttonList->add(
                'saveandcontinue', [
            'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
            'class' => 'save',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit', 'target' => '#edit_form'],
                ],
            ]
                ], -100
        );

        $this->buttonList->update('delete', 'label', __('Delete Field'));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve text for header element depending on loaded post
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getHeaderText() {
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('order_field')->getFieldId()) {
            return __("Edit Field '%1'", $this->escapeHtml($this->_coreRegistry->registry('order_field')->getAttributeLabel()));
        } else {
            return __('New Field');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Getter of url for "Save and Continue" button
     * tab_id will be replaced by desired by JS later
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getSaveAndContinueUrl() {
        return $this->getUrl('orderfield/*/save', ['_current' => true, 'back' => 'edit', 'active_tab' => '{{tab_id}}']);
    }

}
```

And my form file

```
<?php

namespace NAME\MODULENAME\Block\Adminhtml\OrderField\Edit;

class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic {

    /**
     * Prepare form
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm() {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
                ['data' => ['field_id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

currently my output like this

[image]

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Hi @james have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you need to use when initializing the form needs to be "id" rather than "field_id":

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
$form = $this->_formFactory->create(['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout edit block
Change your layout=""admin-2columns-left" to layout="admin-1column"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="styles"/>
<update handle="editor"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        .. Block content tab
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="left">
       .. Block tabs
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Tabs extends WidgetTabs
{
/**
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setId('ultranoir_menumanager_item_form');
    $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
    $this->setTitle(__('Item Information'));
}
}
```

The value of $this->setDestElementId has to be 'edit_form' as the field_id your defined in namespace NAME\MODULENAME\Block\Adminhtml\OrderField\Edit;

```
$form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['field_id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
    );
```